# Match a string with a condition to stop at certain character

Tags: regex

I have a pattern of this:

```
"?(.*)"? <?
```

and I have an input string of:

```
Hello World
"Empire State" <sample@gmail.com>
```

However when I tried to test it I got

```
Hello
Empire State
```

instead of

```
Hello World
Empire State
```

The pattern will get words inside `"` and `"` if its available and then stop at `<` if its also available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that maybe,

```
[^"\r\n]+(?="|[\r\n])
```

might be just OK to extract those.

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/SY2dP8/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/SY2dP8/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---